# How to get a method return type with scala meta annotation?

Tags: scala, scalameta

I want do a Log annotation use scala meta.Usage simple as:

```
@Log
def f1(a: Int) {
    Future(a + 1) //result is a Future
}

// after parsed ====>
def f1(a: Int) {
    Future(a + 1).map{x => 
        println(x)
        x
    }
}
```

How can I check if `f1` is a `Future[ _ ]` type? Thanks
Besides, I don't want use reflection(performance cost) in `Log` annotation and I think method result type can be decided at compile time.

Comment: i am unsure what are you trying to check what is this @Log supposed to do? Why cant you use a function def like `def f1[A](a: Int): Future[A] = ???` then it will fail compile time when its not a Future

Comment: @LeMoN.xaH, thanks your advice.But what I want to do is print the method's result as a log infomation. If result is `Future` the meaningful things is print `Future`'s value rather Future itself. :-) So I use macro do a `map` operation if the method return a Future value.

Comment: You may create a separate log annotations for sync and async methods.
Please consider the following implementation that will likely cover your usecase:
https://github.com/eugengarkusha/macroLogging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible with scalameta macro annotations. The macro annotations are syntactic so they don't have access to semantic information such as types of trees.

PS. I am not sure if a macro annotation is suitable for this use-case, you could write out the log statement explicitly with something like this

```
def log[T](x: T): T = { println(x); x }
Future(1).map(log)
```

or even more concisely with an extension method

```
implicit class XtensionFuture[T](future: Future[T]) {
  def logged: Future[T] = future.map(log)
}
Future(1).logged
```

Macros should ideally be used as a last resort, not for convenience only.

Comment: Hi, I want to log http request's invoke chain that contains all of the important method's context info.Writing by hand anywhere with `log.info/warning/error` is very boring in the situation.Is scalameta will expose semantic info in later roadmap?

Comment: I just found [this](https://github.com/scalameta/scalameta/issues/604).Is semantic info could be access when it finished?

Comment: Macro annotations will likely remain syntactic even after the introduction of the semantic api. Would you still need to write the log.info by hand everywhere with the `.logged` approach I proposed? Scala has plenty of tools to abstract over boilerplate, macros are really the last line of defence and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: Thanks for your detail.I will persist use scalameta do the log andI think the logging can be achieved only by scalameta. About the logger tools for detail see [git repo](https://github.com/LoranceChen/meta-logger#how-does-it-works) if you interesting ;-)